# 2 identical directives with different template

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have 2 identical directives in terms of controller and params, but they use a different template.

The directive is something like this

```
.directive('a', function() {

        return {
            restrict: 'E',
            replace: true,
            scope: {
                data: '=',
                namef: '&'
            },
            controller: function($scope) {                                      
                $scope.name1 = $scope.namef({code: $scope.data.units[0].code});
                $scope.name2 = $scope.namef({code: $scope.data.units[1].code});
            },
            templateUrl: 'a.html',
        };      
    })
```

And there's another one 'b' which looks the same but with template b.html
Then both directives are used like this:

```
<div>   
    <div class="class1" id="{{mydata.id}}">mydata.id</div>
    <div class="class2">
        <a data="mydata[unit]" partic="getName(code)"></a>
        <b data="mydata[unit]" partic="getName(code)"></b>  
    </div>
<div>
```

I was wondering if there's a way of doing this without repeating the same code. I read about creating a service and call it from the controller, but that only solves the issue within the controller.

I know it's not a big deal as the directive is quite simple, but as I'm very new to angular I thought maybe there's a "nice" way to do something like this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one solution that removes duplicate code but allows you to have two "identical" directives except for the templateUrl:

First define a function that returns a directive definition object with the correct url:

```
function getDefObject(templateUrl) {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        replace: true,
        scope: {
            data: '=',
            namef: '&'
        },
        controller: function($scope) {                                      
            $scope.name1 = $scope.namef({code: $scope.data.units[0].code});
            $scope.name2 = $scope.namef({code: $scope.data.units[1].code});
        },
        templateUrl: templateUrl,
    }    
}
```

Then you simply have to call it:

```
.directive('a', function() {
        return getDefObject('a.html');      
    })
.directive('b', function() {
    return getDefObject('b.html');      
})
```

You should probably rename getDefObject and move it into a service, but the idea comes across I hope.

Answer (score 1):

`templateUrl` property (and `template` for that matter) accept a function, so you can select the template based on an some attribute:

```
.directive("foo", function(){
  return {
    templateUrl: function(tElement, tAttrs){
       // or any other logic
       return tAttrs.type === "typeA"? "a.html" : "b.html";
    },
    // etc ...
});
```

The usage is:

```
<foo type="typeA" data="mydata[unit]" partic="getName(code)"></foo>
```

Note, that you **cannot** use an expression like `type="{{typeVar}}"` since it would not be interpolated at the time it is evaluated by the `templateUrl` function.

Comment: Why not simply use `tElement.prop('tagName').toLowerCase()`, which would return "a" or "b".

Comment: @Strille, it is purely a matter of choice. I chose the directive to be `<foo>` - which could be an element, rather than relying on `<a>` (which, come to think of it, is taken :))

Answer (score 0):

Is making one directive an option? If yes, then you can use a function that will return a templateUrl based on an attribute.

```
.directive('ab', function() {

    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        replace: true,
        scope: {
            data: '=',
            namef: '&'
        },
        controller: function($scope) {                                      
            $scope.name1 = $scope.namef({code: $scope.data.units[0].code});
            $scope.name2 = $scope.namef({code: $scope.data.units[1].code});
        },
        templateUrl: function(element,attrs){
                if(attrs.type == "a" ){
                    return "a.html"
                }else if(attrs.type == "b"){
                    return "b.html"
                }else{ return "unknown.html" }
        }
    };      
})
```

Of course you can add some fallback option.

Answer (score -1):

Would this suffice?

```
.directive('a', function() {
        return {
            restrict: 'E',
            replace: true,
            scope: {
                data: '=',
                namef: '&'
            },
            controller: 'sharedController',
            templateUrl: 'a.html',
        };      
    })  
.directive('b', function() {
        return {
            restrict: 'E',
            replace: true,
            scope: {
                data: '=',
                namef: '&'
            },
            controller: 'sharedController',
            templateUrl: 'b.html',
        };      
    })
.controller('sharedController', function($scope){
    $scope.name1 = $scope.namef({code: $scope.data.units[0].code});
    $scope.name2 = $scope.namef({code: $scope.data.units[1].code});
});
```

Comment: That works and of course it looks cleaner. I was thinking in something more radical, sort of `b = new a()` so that you don´t need to declare again all the other attributes (restrict, replace, scope and so on). Is that even possible? Otherwise, your answer would suit me fine, @mathew-berg